# Populating an array with include directives

Tags: arrays, include, static-linking, precompile

This morning I learned that the famous videogame Super Mario 64 has been fully decompiled back to C source code. Just out of curiosity, I've decided to look through it, and I noticed something that I had never seen before.

```
// 0x09000000
ALIGNED8 const u8 machine_09000000[] = {
#include "textures/machine/ttc_textures.00000.rgba16.inc.c"
};
```

It looks like they put an include directive inside of an array. This is done repeatedly throughout the whole program.
I've been studying C for a little while now, and I consider myself reasonably fluent with this language, but this is something extremely novel to me and I've got so many questions about it.

1) Is it actually legal or even recommended to do something like this?
2) Why would you do this?
3) Why is the include referring to a *.c file?
4) Why is the type set to u8 (which should be a standard alias for unsigned char, if I've got that straight)?
5) What's that ALIGNED8 macro? Is it something standard?

I've tried to gather information on my own, but wasn't able to find much on this topic. If you want to look at the source code yourself, here's the link: https://github.com/n64decomp/sm64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a fellow a bit brighter than myself-

1 & 2: we're including an image converted into C. There are other techniques for this than arrays within .c code, but that's the technique the sm64 devs used, so we mimic it. And instead of copy-pasting C array we have the build system generate (parts of) C from images automatically, which then #included. It works decently well, best we could do under the circumstances. (Assuming we want to keep everything in C instead of assembly -- in assembly we'd .incbin which would be cleaner, but it becomes less portable.)

3: .h would be wrong, since it's not a header file that declares functions, types, etc., but rather data (a partial C file)

4. it's u8 because the file we're including is just a binary blob of data, and we don't want to make endianness assumptions
5. ALIGNED8 is actually ignored on IDO. Its effect is to 8-byte-align the array on GCC. The reason is that addresses sent to the RSP have to be 8-byte-aligned, and that's not guaranteed without such a directive. In particular, GCC happily reorders variables in ways that make them non-8-byte-aligned. IDO doesn't do that sort of reordering (it just emits arrays in source order), but the variables just happen to end up 8-byte-aligned there anyway.
   it helps to know what #include does, which is just include the text of another file
   from that definition it follows that yes, it's absolutely legal to use it in that context; whether it's wise is another question.

Comment: Thank you for replying! This is really interesting and actually much less cryptic that I thought it was. Let's see if I got this straight: basically an image is decoded in chunks of 8 bits inside of a *.c file (one for each texture or whatever) which represent that picture. It is a *.c because you wouldn't be able to do something like this in a header file.

Comment: Then an array of bytes is initialized putting an include directive inside of it. The *.c which the include references contains only the set of bytes that represent the image, so when the precompiler does his thing, the include gets substituted with those elements, properly initializing the array. Then that array will represent the image in the rest of the code. It looks like a weird and convoluted solution, but it's also pretty ingenious. Did I get any of that wrong?

Comment: Yeah you are completely right. Happy this helped ya, if you ever are looking for more help just let me know.

Comment: Thank you again! I might check that discord server out as soon as I will have a little bit of free time, this stuff is really interesting.  For the time being, I'll confirm your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Before I go into anything, let me first recommend using the Discord link attached to that repo, discord.gg/27JtCWs . I will do the best to answer this, but am definitely not the most knowledgeable of standards and typical behavior for coding in-general. My experience is only relevant since I work closely with some individuals involved with the decompilation.

1 & 2. I don't believe that this is a sane thing to generally do, however it is important to remember the point of the repo- allow modifications easily to the codebase while preserving its ability to compile a 1:1 ROM of SM64. Having the file split up makes finding the relevant locations of things easier, although this particular one is not well named yet.

3. So the inc.c files are glorified header files, just inserting their code in that location. It's named a .c file because it is sort of C, just not a legitimate C file itself. That's why it's .inc.c, since it is INCluded>
4. It is a standard unsigned char, that is correct. This can be found in types.h. This is done because really its just importing a bunch of data that can be read separately. This particular file isn't in the repo, but if you extract assets you can see that is is an image being inserted there. The image's data is just split up into u8's and put there, allowing it be both be extracted/inserted and more easily edited.
5. ALIGNED8 is for the compiler. The IDO 5.7 compiler that the repository uses often aligns things within the ROM output, and the ALIGN8 directive is telling it to pad out to 8 bytes. If the ALIGNED8 was not there, it would potentially insert that data too soon, shifting the ROM.

Hope I didn't make any mistakes and this helps. It's just important to remember that the whole GitHub isn't really a typical one, since its less about worrying about internal consistency and more worrying about external (ROM) consistency, often meaning that sometimes solutions have to be sort-of hacked together to allow functionality. If you have further questions I will again recommend asking in the Discord, as those guys are much more informed than I am.